# Crystal report HTML RTL direction not working with Arabic

Tags: crystal-reports, arabic, direction

I am trying to generate a report which gets data as html from database to be displayed as multi records in ARABIC. Data is being retrieved successfully, but the problem is when I try to display Arabic Unordered List (`<ul>` and `<li>` html tags), items are being displayed from left to right instead of right to left. Below is the output of all trials: [image: Check this image]

I have tried multiple structures but I got same result:

**Trial 1:**

```
: الأرقام هي 
<ul style="direction:rtl;" dir="rtl">
  <li>واحد</li>
  <li>إثنان</li>
  <li>ثلاثة</li>
</ul>
```

**Trial 2:**

```
: الأرقام هي 
<ul style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;" dir="rtl">
  <li>واحد</li>
  <li>إثنان</li>
  <li>ثلاثة</li>
</ul>
```

**Trial 3:**

```
: الأرقام هي 
<ul style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;" dir="rtl">
  <li style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;" dir="rtl">واحد</li>
  <li style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;" dir="rtl">إثنان</li>
  <li style="direction:rtl; text-align:right;" dir="rtl">ثلاثة</li>
</ul>
```

Nothing has changed in all trials, any help?

**Update**

Horizontal Alignment and Reading Order of crystal report formula are set to right;
I have also added a new trial where I have put the whole content in a new div, but unfortunately all text was displayed from left to right:

**Trial 4:**

```
<div style="direction:rtl; text-align: right"  >
  : الأرقام هي 
    <ul style="direction:rtl;" dir="rtl">
      <li>واحد</li>
      <li>إثنان</li>
      <li>ثلاثة</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crystal has limited support for html interpretation.

One way to get around this is to create or get a UFL that turns the HTML to an image. Crystal can dynamically generate and load the image into the report (using the 'graphic location' property).

Here is an example using your text with a few tweaks:
[image]

Comment: @MiletSoftware wow! This is the first time I hear about UFL, I will search for it and revert back; Thank you for your reply

Comment: @MiletSoftware  did you create a new function or you used a published library? Is it possible to share the solution? links, codes anything... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by using the below:

```
    : الأرقام هي 
    <ul align = "right" dir="rtl">
      <li align = "right" >واحد</li>
      <li align = "right" >إثنان</li>
      <li align = "right" >ثلاثة</li>
    </ul>
```

I hope this can help somebody